# Always "Resolving host" on initial connection until Wifi restart

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

Lots of questions about "resolving host" but I can't find any that deal specifically with initial connections.  When I try to connect my Macbook (mid-2012 13 inch, Yosemite 10.10.3) to an already setup network for the first time of the day - e.g. when tethering to android or arriving at work - the browser belligerently sticks to "resolving host" until I switch wifi off and back on, despite ostensibly having a full connection wifi icon.  Then the connection is fine.  This happens pretty consistently.  Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have a custom DNS resolver address under the "Advanced" connection settings in `System Preferences > Network > WiFi > Advanced > DNS`?

Answer (score 2):

I think on the same line as ryebread:
in SystemPreferences->Network->WiFi chosen at the left side->Advanced->DNS tab:
put in
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
with the plus sign
then OK - Apply.